# Change color of pie chart on drilldown

Tags: highcharts

I've a pie chart with drilldown data and like to change the chart.options.colors. Is there a way to replace the whole color array in chart.options.colors on drilldown, and restore the old color array to chart.options.colors on drillup?

Tried to change the array in chart.options.colors and to call redraw(), but it does not work correctly.

Thank you

Torben

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in a quite old fashioned way by giving the color to every point you wish to have.

in data section:

```
data: [24,28,{
        y: 40,
        color: 'red'
    }, 10, 30, 40
]
```

here I've worked out a example : http://jsfiddle.net/tbjuq/

I hope this will help you to achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace every element of the series array

```
{
 name: 'sampleName',
 id: 'sampleId',
 data: [
    ['subElement1', value1],
    ['subElement2', value2]
] 
}
```

with

```
{
name: 'sampleName',
id: 'sampleId',
data: [{
        name: 'subElement1',
        y: value1,
        color: '#123456'
    },
    {
        name: 'subElement2',
        y: value2,
        color: '#123456'
    }
]}
```

Comment: I'm at a loss as to how this actually answers the question. If you are indeed trying to provide an answer to the question please add more context.